# Only last item in RecyclerView gets updated when notifyDataSetChanged is called

Tags: android, kotlin, checkbox, android-recyclerview, multi-select

I want to build a **segment wise list** with **selection feature**.
For this I have multiple RecyclerViews (for e.g. 5) in my layout file and the data list of each recyclerview is dynamic.[As you can see in this image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FJphp.png)

Now, each item in recyclerview has a **checkbox**. What I need to do is when user selects any item, only those items of that perticular list should be enabled and other segment's list items should be disabled.

The issue I am facing is when I am trying to update each recyclerview using **notifyDataSetChanged**, only last item in the list is disabled and rest are enabled. I debugged the app, and process wise everything is working fine but the app doesn't reflect the same.[As you can see here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cLfzl.png)

My data model -

```
data class SelectionModel(
    var channelType: String,
    var channelName: String,
    var devices: ArrayList<SelectiveDevice>?
) {
    data class SelectiveDevice(
        var deviceName: String,
        var deviceType: String,
        var selected: Boolean = false
    )
}
```

My MainActivity -

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity(), FiveChannelDeviceAdapter.FiveChannelDeviceCallback, FourChannelDeviceAdapter.FourChannelDeviceCallback, ThreeChannelDeviceAdapter.ThreeChannelDeviceCallback, TwoChannelDeviceAdapter.TwoChannelDeviceCallback, OneChannelDeviceAdapter.OneChannelDeviceCallback {

    lateinit var mBinding: ActivityMainBinding
    private var segments = ArrayList<SelectionModel>()

    private lateinit var fiveChannelDeviceAdapter: FiveChannelDeviceAdapter
    private lateinit var fourChannelDeviceAdapter: FourChannelDeviceAdapter
    private lateinit var threeChannelDeviceAdapter: ThreeChannelDeviceAdapter
    private lateinit var twoChannelDeviceAdapter: TwoChannelDeviceAdapter
    private lateinit var oneChannelDeviceAdapter: OneChannelDeviceAdapter

    var selectedType = ""
    var selectedGroup = ""
    var countChecked = 0
    var devices5ch = ArrayList<SelectionModel.SelectiveDevice>()
    var devices3ch = ArrayList<SelectionModel.SelectiveDevice>()
    var devices1ch = ArrayList<SelectionModel.SelectiveDevice>()

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        mBinding = DataBindingUtil.setContentView(this, R.layout.activity_main)

        fiveChannelDeviceAdapter = FiveChannelDeviceAdapter(this@MainActivity, this@MainActivity)
        fourChannelDeviceAdapter = FourChannelDeviceAdapter(this@MainActivity, this@MainActivity)
        threeChannelDeviceAdapter = ThreeChannelDeviceAdapter(this@MainActivity, this@MainActivity)
        twoChannelDeviceAdapter = TwoChannelDeviceAdapter(this@MainActivity, this@MainActivity)
        oneChannelDeviceAdapter = OneChannelDeviceAdapter(this@MainActivity, this@MainActivity)

        mBinding.rvFiveCh.adapter = fiveChannelDeviceAdapter
        mBinding.rvFourCh.adapter = fourChannelDeviceAdapter
        mBinding.rvThreeCh.adapter = threeChannelDeviceAdapter
        mBinding.rvTwoCh.adapter = twoChannelDeviceAdapter
        mBinding.rvOneCh.adapter = oneChannelDeviceAdapter

        segments.clear()
        devices5ch.clear()
        devices3ch.clear()
        devices1ch.clear()

        val device1 = SelectionModel.SelectiveDevice("First", "5ch", false)
        val device2 = SelectionModel.SelectiveDevice("Second", "5ch", false)
        val device3 = SelectionModel.SelectiveDevice("Third", "5ch", false)
        val device4 = SelectionModel.SelectiveDevice("Forth", "3ch", false)
        val device5 = SelectionModel.SelectiveDevice("Fifth", "3ch", false)
        val device6 = SelectionModel.SelectiveDevice("Sixth", "1ch", false)

        devices5ch.add(device1)
        devices5ch.add(device2)
        devices5ch.add(device3)

        devices3ch.add(device4)
        devices3ch.add(device5)

        devices1ch.add(device6)

        val segment5ch = SelectionModel("5ch", "Color & CCT Lights", devices5ch)
        val segment3ch = SelectionModel("3ch", "Color Lights", devices3ch)
        val segment1ch = SelectionModel("1ch", "White Lights", devices1ch)

        segments.add(segment5ch)
        segments.add(segment3ch)
        segments.add(segment1ch)

        fiveChannelDeviceAdapter.setAdapterData(segments[0].devices!!, selectedType, selectedGroup, countChecked)
        threeChannelDeviceAdapter.setAdapterData(segments[1].devices!!, selectedType, selectedGroup, countChecked)
        oneChannelDeviceAdapter.setAdapterData(segments[2].devices!!, selectedType, selectedGroup, countChecked)

    }

    override fun resetSelection() {
        selectedType = ""
        selectedGroup = ""
        countChecked = 0

        fiveChannelDeviceAdapter.setAdapterData(segments[0].devices!!, selectedType, selectedGroup, countChecked)
        threeChannelDeviceAdapter.setAdapterData(segments[1].devices!!, selectedType, selectedGroup, countChecked)
        oneChannelDeviceAdapter.setAdapterData(segments[2].devices!!, selectedType, selectedGroup, countChecked)
    }

    override fun setReverseData(
        selectedType: String,
        selectedGroup: String,
        countChecked: Int,
        deviceList: ArrayList<SelectionModel.SelectiveDevice>
    ) {
        this.selectedType = selectedType
        this.selectedGroup = selectedGroup
        this.countChecked = countChecked
        val alteredList = java.util.ArrayList<SelectionModel>()
        alteredList.addAll(segments)

        for (group in alteredList) {
            if (group.channelType.equals(this.selectedType, true)) {
                group.devices = deviceList
            }
        }

        fiveChannelDeviceAdapter.setAdapterData(alteredList[0].devices!!, selectedType, selectedGroup, countChecked)
        threeChannelDeviceAdapter.setAdapterData(alteredList[1].devices!!, selectedType, selectedGroup, countChecked)
        oneChannelDeviceAdapter.setAdapterData(alteredList[2].devices!!, selectedType, selectedGroup, countChecked)

    }
}
```

One of the Adapter -

```
class FiveChannelDeviceAdapter(
    private val context: Context,
    private val callback: FiveChannelDeviceCallback
) :
    RecyclerView.Adapter<FiveChannelDeviceAdapter.FiveChannelDeviceViewHolder>() {

    private var mDeviceLists = ArrayList<SelectionModel.SelectiveDevice>()
    private lateinit var channelDevices: LayoutChannelDeviceBinding

    var selectedTypes = ""
    var selectedGroups = ""
    var countCheckeds = 0

    inner class FiveChannelDeviceViewHolder(itemView: View): RecyclerView.ViewHolder(itemView) {

        fun setData(position: Int) {
            if (countCheckeds > 0) {
                if (mDeviceLists[position].deviceType == selectedTypes) {
                    Log.d("SegmentSelected", position.toString())
                    channelDevices.selectDeviceCheck.setOnCheckedChangeListener(null)
                    channelDevices.selectDeviceCheck.isEnabled = true
                    channelDevices.selectDeviceCheck.isClickable = true
                    channelDevices.selectDeviceCheck.isChecked = mDeviceLists[position].selected
                    channelDevices.tvDeviceName.text = "Enabled"
                } else {
                    Log.d("SegmentNotSelected", position.toString())
                    channelDevices.selectDeviceCheck.isEnabled = false
                    channelDevices.selectDeviceCheck.isClickable = false
                    channelDevices.tvDeviceName.text = "Disabled"
                }
            } else {
                Log.d("SegmentReset", position.toString())
                channelDevices.selectDeviceCheck.isEnabled = true
                channelDevices.selectDeviceCheck.isClickable = true
                channelDevices.tvDeviceName.text = "Enabled"
            }

            channelDevices.selectDeviceCheck.setOnCheckedChangeListener { compoundButton, checked ->
                if (checked) {
                    countCheckeds += 1
                    mDeviceLists[position].selected = checked
                    selectedTypes = mDeviceLists[position].deviceType
                    selectedGroups = selectedTypes
                    Log.d("DeviceList", mDeviceLists.toString())
                    callback.setReverseData(selectedTypes, selectedGroups, countCheckeds, mDeviceLists)
                } else if (countCheckeds > 0 && !checked) {
                    countCheckeds -= 1
                    mDeviceLists[position].selected = checked
                    if (countCheckeds == 0) {
                        countCheckeds = 0
                        selectedTypes = ""
                        selectedGroups = ""
                        callback.resetSelection()
                    } else {
                        callback.setReverseData(selectedTypes, selectedGroups, countCheckeds, mDeviceLists)
                    }
                } else if (countCheckeds == 0 && !checked) {
                    countCheckeds = 0
                    mDeviceLists[position].selected = checked
                    selectedTypes = ""
                    selectedGroups = ""
                    callback.resetSelection()
                }
            }

        }
    }

    override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): FiveChannelDeviceViewHolder {
        channelDevices = LayoutChannelDeviceBinding.inflate(
            LayoutInflater.from(parent.context),
            parent,
            false
        )
        return FiveChannelDeviceViewHolder(channelDevices.root)
    }

    override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: FiveChannelDeviceViewHolder, position: Int) {
        holder.setData(position)
    }

    override fun getItemCount(): Int {
        return mDeviceLists.size
    }

    fun setAdapterData(mDeviceList: ArrayList<SelectionModel.SelectiveDevice>, selectedType: String, selectedGroup: String, countChecked: Int) {
        this.mDeviceLists.clear()
        this.mDeviceLists.addAll(mDeviceList)
        this.selectedTypes = selectedType
        this.selectedGroups = selectedGroup
        this.countCheckeds = countChecked
        notifyDataSetChanged()
    }

    interface FiveChannelDeviceCallback {
        fun resetSelection()
        fun setReverseData(selectedType: String, selectedGroup: String, countChecked: Int, deviceList: ArrayList<SelectionModel.SelectiveDevice>)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried doing these all in a single RecyclerView ?
Using Adapter's getItemViewType() method.

Like, create two layouts :

1. Header Layout [To give the headings to the seciton]
2. Item Layout [One with the CheckBox]

Create a main list, with a sealed class like this

```
sealed class SectionItemUIModel{
    
data class Heading(val heading:String):SectionItemUIModel()
    
data class Item(val sectionItem:SectionItem):SectionItemUIModel()
   
 }
```

Then in recyclerView Adapter, you will have a function called **getItemViewType**

```
override fun getItemViewType(position:Int) = when(getItem(position)){
Heading->0
Item->1
}
```

Now use this in **OnCreateViewHolder(){}** where you will get the argument of the **viewType**

```
override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): when(viewType){
0->HeadingHolder()
1->ItemHolder()
}
```

This will help you to create a single list for all the field and will be easy to handle the selection boolean values to turn ON and OFF.
Also will be shorter approach to be done.